# Poincaré symmetry and linearized gravity

Tags: general-relativity, poincare-symmetry, linearized-theory

When working with linearized gravity, is Poincaré symetry assumed to be the symmetry of space-time?

Comment: As Prahar points out, this is certainly not the case if you choose a non-trivial background for your linearized theory.

Answer (score 1):

If the background around which one is linearizing is Minkowski space, then yes.

Comment: Would you mind clarifying and substantiating this claim?  In particular, are you saying that the Poincare group is necessarily a subgroup of the group of isometries of a spacetime that has been linearized around Minkowski, or are you saying that this is the case to first order?  I haven't worked this out, but it's not obvious to me which (if either) you mean and what precisely the statement is.

Comment: In linearized gravity, the "metric perturbation" is really considered to be some spin-2 field in a Minkowski background. One simply writes down all possible gauge invariant terms in the Lagrangian, just like one does for all other fields, scalars/fermions/gauge fields. Generally, the interpretation of these excitations is of simply some set of excitations in a fixed space-time background, hence making Poincare symmetry a symmetry of the theory (space-time is fixed to be Minkowski).

Comment: This only holds true at the perturbative level though. Non-perturbatively, one can have larger excitations that dominate over the classical background thereby modifying the space-time background.